# Are parenthesis needed to get the address of a struct member from a pointer to the struct as in "&(s->var)" vs "&s->var"?

Tags: c

I have a `struct str *s`;

Let `var` be a variable in `s`. Is `&s->var` equal to `&(s->var)`?

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 50):

Behavior-wise, yes they are equivalent since [the member access `->` operator has a higher precedence than the address-of `&` operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence).

Readibility-wise, the second one `&(s->var)` is much more readable than `&s->var` and should be preferred over the first form. With the second form, `&(s->var)`, you won't have to second-guess what it's actually doing as you know the expression in the parentheses are always evaluated first. When in doubt, use parentheses.

Comment: Visually `&s->var` is less cluttered. But `&(s->var)` shows your intention better. Without parenthesis, you might have a slight mental strain: "Did `&` really have precedence over `->`? Ah, yes, of course". Even if it's just a fraction of a second, that still matters and sometimes can make you feel psychologically strained "Oh, silly me, how could I forget it...". Nowadays I rarely program in C/C++, and other languages do not have address operator, so it's easy to forget it. That's why I use parenthesis in C/C++ more than normally needed - just to avoid embarrassing myself later on :)

Answer (score 7):

Yes.

(-> is higher precedence than &.  See http://cppreference.com/wiki/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: Although the link is for C++ operator precedence, this answer agrees with those operators such as & (address-of) and -> (member selection) that are common to C.  A C operator precedence table is [in these class notes](http://www.difranco.net/cop2220/op-prec.htm) and may also be inferred from [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B) that puts them side-by-side.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, because the pointer dereference operator `->` has higher precedence than the address operator `&`.

- [C operator precedence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence)